# Impedir mídia de continuar carregando na tag <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, streaming

Tenho um player em audio na página, e recarrego o source através de javascript.
Porém toda vez que carrego um audio novo, o antigo continua carregando, apesar de não estar mais reproduzindo. E isso está atrapalhando o desempenho da minha aplicação. É como se o audio antigo apenas ficasse mudo.

Vejam na imagem abaixo, o meu problema. Cada "stream.mp3" é uma fonte de audio diferente, que foi "trocada" pela posterior após uma ação. veja que as anteriores apesar de não estarem reproduzindo, continuam a carregar.

Minha pergunta é existe uma forma de "destruir" isso, zerar antes de carregar uma fonte de audio nova?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está o código javascript?

Comment: Já testaste remover o elemento do DOM e voltar a inserir com o novo link?

Comment: Aqui está o código, resumindo eu removo o elemento existente, crio um novo e carrego o audio. Toda vez assim,mas o anterior persiste carregando em background. http://prntscr.com/7gypct

Comment: Podes criar um jsFIddle ou algum exemplo que possâmos testar? assim podemos ver também o devtools e testar.

Comment: Vou colocar, estou simplificando o codigo para tal.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme está resposta do SOen seria remover o player antigo e adicionar um novo com a nova faixa de audio:

Um exemplo rapido usando jQuery:

```
var audio = $("#audio-player audio").get(0);
audio.pause(0); //Pausa o player 
audio.src = ""; //Remove a faixa
audio.load();   //Dispara o load 
$("audio").remove();//Remove o audio

$('<audio controls preload="none"></audio>').appendTo("#audio-player");

audio = $("#audio-player audio").get(0);
audio.src = NOVO AUDIO;
```

Para resumir o processo é:

1. Pausar o `<audio>`
2. Setar vazio no `src`
3. Executar o evento `audio.load();`
4. Remover o elemento `audio`

> Não adicionei detalhes pois o `7.` da explicação da postagem ficou confusa e a nota que está abaixo explica legal sobre o iOS, mas não deixa claro se o treco que ele afirma em `meu caso` é o Desktop ou outra coisa

Comment: Seu código está parecido com o meu que uso atualmente, na ordem dos eventos. Vou tentar assim mesmo. Agradeço muito

Comment: @FabioWeydson se quiser adicionar o seu código na pergunta eu talvez possa adicionar um exemplo para adiantar o seu lado